# Android: why can't I call setOnClickListener method on a button outside of an onCreate method?

Tags: java, android

This is a newbie question but why can't I call setOnClickListener method on a button outside of an onCreate method?

For example why can't I do this? Or maybe Eclipse just don't have setOnClickListener code hinting outside of onCreate method? Cause nothing shows up.

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main_layout);
}


Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_send);
   button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
     public void onClick(View v) {
      // Do something in response to button click
  }
});
```

Comment: is your code even inside of a method? This is definitely possible, I just did this in my app 5 minutes ago.

Comment: Is that in a method or just random code in the class? Looks like you might need to go back to Java 101.

Comment: yes, It seems it is not calling under any method. @ColinGillespie how did you achieved to do the same?.

Comment: @vinaykumar it doesn't matter where as long as setContentView() has been called before you add your listener. (You can't just dump code randomly in the class of course)

Comment: @ColinGillespie I am totally agree with you " it doesn't matter where as long as setContentView() has been called before", but you check the above code it seems button.setOnclickListener() is not been called under any method, I think this cause the issue. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Answer (score 5):

You can setonclicklistener in any function. But this is not your exact problem.
Actual problem is

```
setContentView(R.layout.main_layout);
```

you can call **findViewById** function after **setContentView**. **setContentView** is used to set layout on an activity. Your layout contains different views like buttons etc. So if you will not set your layout then you cannot access your views by using findViewById and if you cannot access then you cannot use them.

So proper sequence will be:

```
1 Set layout on your activity using setContentView.
2 Find id for your view using findViewById.
3 Then use your views for your purposes.
```

Always concentrate on basics first.

One more problem is you are calling setOnClickListener outside any function. Outside any function static blocks, function declaration and assignments are only allowed. Below statement is neither of them. So it will never execute and callback will never occur.

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
     public void onClick(View v) {
      // Do something in response to button click
  }
```

});

Answer (score 1):

**onCreate** is sort of your **main(String[] args)** function in normal Java. It is where you setup your code.Also see this link:-

[Noob question about "Hello World" Android tutorial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7358219/noob-question-about-hello-world-android-tutorial)

This the right way:-

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.main_layout);
    Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_send);
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
 public void onClick(View v) {
  // Do something in response to button click
 }
});
}
```

or

This is the another way to achieve your task:-

```
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.main_layout);
    Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_send);
button.setOnClickListener(onClick);
}


public OnClickListener onClick= new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        // Do something in response to button click
    }
};
```

Comment: everything after setContentView();. as long as setContentView() has been called it doesn't matter where you set your listeners

Comment: Are you serious @ColinGillespie ?

Comment: what you have done is correct. I am just saying it doesn't matter as long as setContentView() has already been called.

Answer (score 0):

Only after the `setContentView(R.layout.main_layout);` is called you get access to the components inside that view (i.e. the button).
Because the declaration and instantation of the button is written in the main class context it happens **before** the `setContentView`.

Insert the button code section inside the onCreate and it will work.

Answer (score 0):

Example

```
public class yourActivityName extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.main_layout);

       Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_send);
       button.setOnClickListener(this);

   }



    @Override

       public void onClick(View v) {

        if (v.getId() == R.id.button_send) {

            //your code..

        }
       }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that is because you want the listeners to be added as soon as the code executes. If you put is outside, which is very much technically, possible, your code will not be executed (of course unless you intend to call the method from within the onCreate method.

Answer (score 0):

register the onClickListner for each button like.

```
button.setOnClickListener(this);
```

and override this method

```
@Override
public void onClick ( View v )
{
     if ( v == button ) 
     {
            // your code...
     }

   ////  add others...
}
```

implement OnClickListener in your activity

```
public class yourActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener
```

Answer (score 0):

This problem can be fixed writing the code within the {} of:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
```

Below the:

```
setContentView(R.layout.main_layout);
```